# SQLITE DISTINCT COUNT within a strftime statement throwing error

Tags: pandas, sqlite, strftime

I have a query in SQLite through Pandas in a jupyter notebook.

The below query runs as expected except I want the dayofweek_count to count the number of occurences of each weekday.  There can be more than one entry for each day (i.e. Monday 2/17/20 could have 4 entries but I only want Monday 2/17/20 counted once)

```
df_total_weekday=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT CASE cast(strftime('%w', event_date) as integer)" 
    "when 0 then 'Sunday'"
    "when 1 then 'Monday'"
    "when 2 then 'Tuesday'"
    "when 3 then 'Wednesday'"
    "when 4 then 'Thursday'" 
    "when 5 then 'Friday'"
    "else 'Saturday' end as dayofweek"
    ",COUNT(strftime('%w', event_date)) as dayofweek_count"
    ",SUM(quantity) as total_quantity FROM subscription_data GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY strftime('%w', event_date)",conn,parse_dates=['event_date'])
```

But this query throws a syntax error near DISTINCT, but I cannot seem to figure out why.  I have tried DISTINCT (event_date) as well as DISTINCT event_date.

```
df_total_weekday=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT CASE cast(strftime('%w', event_date) as integer)" 
        "when 0 then 'Sunday'"
        "when 1 then 'Monday'"
        "when 2 then 'Tuesday'"
        "when 3 then 'Wednesday'"
        "when 4 then 'Thursday'" 
        "when 5 then 'Friday'"
        "else 'Saturday' end as dayofweek"
        ",COUNT(strftime('%w',DISTINCT event_date)) as dayofweek_count"
        ",SUM(quantity) as total_quantity FROM subscription_data GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY strftime('%w', event_date)",conn,parse_dates=['event_date'])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Consider making a [mre].  I recommend to provide a tailored toy database in the shape of a few lines of `creat table ...` and `insert ...` which can be used in the SQLite commandline tool. I suspect the DISTINCT is in the wrong place and want to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(strftime('%w',DISTINCT event_date))
```

That's a syntax error because `strftime()` doesn't understand `DISTINCT`; it's not an aggregate function (And with aggregate functions, it only works on ones with a single argument). `COUNT(strftime(...))` doesn't make much sense anyways unless some of your `event_date` values are't accepted date/time strings (Which would make `strftime()` return `NULL`).

Comment: The goal of this query is to get the days of the week and associated count of each as well as the sum of the associated quantities attached to each entry.  There can be multiple (or none) entries per date.  Is it then possible to have a query that will output :  SUNDAY, 43, 12909 with 43 being the number of unique dates that are Sunday and 12909 being the sum of quantities attached to a Sunday date?